# How to put Doc comments for Dart function parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart

We can easily put Doc comments for Dart Class variables e.g.

```
class SomeClass {
/// Class variable Doc Comment.
var someVariable;

}
```

How can I do the same for Dart Function parameters e.g. I tried this

```
void someFunction(
 {/// Function parameter documentation
 String funParameter="Some Default Value"}
) {

}
```

But it's not showing anything. If it's not possible please suggest me any alternative.

Answer (score 23):

It is [against the Effective Dart conventions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#do-use-prose-to-explain-parameters-return-values-and-exceptions) to document parameters of functions using a direct syntax like that. Instead, use prose to describe the parameter and how it relates to the function's purpose.

```dart
// Instead of this

/// someFunction
/// @funParameter Does something fun
void someFunction({ String funParameter="Some Default Value" }) ...

// Or this

/// someFunction
void someFunction({
  /// Does something fun
  String funParameter="Some Default Value" 
}) ...

// Do this

/// Does something fun with the [funParameter].
void someFunction({ String funParameter="Some Default Value" }) ...
```

Here's perhaps a more practical example:

```dart
/// Takes the values [a] and [b] and returns their sum. Optionally a
/// third parameter [c] can be provided and it will be added to the 
/// sum as well.
int add(int a, int b, [int c = 0]) ...
```

Comment: How can I do this for multiple parameters as I tried this and all those are mixing together?

Comment: @ShahzadAkram The same way. Surround the name of each parameter in brackets like shown.

Comment: Yes, I did that but this is also showing docs for all other parameters.

Comment: @ShahzadAkram I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ShahzadAkram You don't document individual function parameters.  You document the function, and the function's documentation describes the parameters.  For examples, see existing Dart SDK documentation, such as for [`String.replaceAllMapped`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html).  The documentation page includes a link to the source code so you can see how the original code comment looks.

Comment: This is tremendously stupid. This google's standard go against every other single language standard about code comments.

For starters, this prevent IDEs from using autocompletion for code comments.

It also prevents any documentation generator that is not google's from understanding the syntax.

Comment: @AdrianLopez Possibly, but it also helps promote human-readable documentation that can be read and understood without the need for a specialized docstring parser. Also, citation needed on that "every other single language standard" claim, since Python, Go, and Rust use a similar docstring approach to this as well.

Comment: Rust is quite standard, it follows the same notation other languages like C# do (///). And even though python, and most languages adapt it to some extent to their needs, all of them are still parseable. I would know, I've implemented all of then: https://github.com/rafamadriz/friendly-snippets/issues/327

Comment: @AdrianLopez You seem to have confused the Rust standard on docstrings as being some rigid docstring format. From a technical standpoint, the only standard that Rust enforces is the triple-slash comment with a Markdown-enabled docstring, and everything beyond that is just convention. Well, guess what? Dart uses triple-slash comments with Markdown-enabled docstrings, and Google's best practices aside, there's absolutely nothing stopping you from following the Rust convention in Dart. (I mean, have you _seen_ the docstrings for Flutter widget classes? It's literally a wall of Markdown text.)

Comment: Don't see, why this syntax is preventing IDEs to do code completion. However the "official" IDE Android Studio with Dart plugin does not understand this syntax: Try to rename a parameter (Shift-F6) and you end up with broken documentation, since the parameter reference in the doc comment was not renamed consistently. Renaming a class however works well. It also renames references in the doc comments like [MyClass].

Answer (score 9):

You should use the doc comment like this:

```dart
/// the function uses [funParameter] to do stuff
void someFunction({String funParameter = "Some Default Value"}) {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for multiple parameters as I tried and all those Docs are mixing together?

Comment: Yes, you just enclose the parameter name in `[` and `]`.